# Create recursive Python function with multiple conditions

Tags: python, recursion

Background: I am trying to write a function that parses message data out of a plain text document I've converted from a PDF. I've parsed and cleaned the data up to a convenient point, such that each line of relevant text is recognized and labeled with an appropriate category. The categories are `(Author, Sent, Body, Attachments)`.

The problem: I am trying to write a function that will separate out data into individual messages. For instance, after it process a line (or lines) belonging to each category, it will output a singular message and then repeat the process once it encounters the beginning of the tuple again. In other words, once it reads `Author` then `Sent` then `Body` then `Attachments`, when it sees `Author` again, it should know to start a new message.

I've created a variable `next_category` that determines, as the name implies, the category of the upcoming line. So long as the index of the upcoming category is not `0`, the function should operate. When it the next category is `0`, it should repeat the operation on the new lines, until it reaches `0` again, and so on.

Finally, there's a condition wherein `next_category` can equal `None` in which case the function should exit completely.

The code:

```
    def message_parse(thread_dict):
        categories = ('Author', 'Sent', 'Body', 'Attachments')
        category = None


        for line in range(len(thread_dict['data'])):
            # determine first word in line
            first_word = thread_dict['data'][line].split(' ')[0]

            try:
                # determine first word in upcoming line
                next_first = first_word = thread_dict['data'][line+1].split(' ')[0]
            except:
                next_first = None

            if next_first in categories:
                next_category = next_first

            if first_word in categories:
                category = first_word


                if category != None:
                    line_data = thread_dict['data'][line]
                    if not 'DRAFT' in line_data:
                        if line_data != 'EXC':
                            line_data = line_data.strip(category).strip(' ')

                        while next_first != None:    
                            if categories.index(next_category) != 0:
                                # do something?
```

My instinct tells me I need to create a recursive function to accomplish this, but I've hit a wall trying to come up with something. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks so much.

Comment: Why do you feel the need to recurse? Also, what is your input data like?

Comment: Iterate and solve this, this does not really require a recursion.

Comment: I agree with @ParitoshSingh , this is not a recursion problem, it's a parsing problem.  Also, this type of data would work well as a CSV, it would make parsing far easier.

Comment: @MadPhysicist What feels like recursion to me is the fact that I need to loop through the categories list, perform operation(s), then stop once all categories have been seen once and perform those same operations again on a new set of lines, and repeat in perpetuity until the final condition is met. The original input is a PDF document that is converted to text.

Comment: Sounds like a loop, not recursion to me. Granted that the two can be used interchangeably, but I don't think you want to be creating a potentially infinite number of stack frames.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I can only loop through the tuple and process the data successfully one time. I'm having trouble finding a way to make it run continuously over all the lines, parsing out individual messages each time. Still, it sounds like the consensus is that recursion is not the solution I'm looking for. I guess I'll vote to have this question closed and work with loops and see if I can't solve it that way.

Comment: Sounds good. Take a look at nested loops: a loop inside another loop. The outer one keeps going as long as necessary, the inner one processes items.

Comment: this will be recursive, if one's message body contains another message. Can that be a case @J.Behnken?

Comment: @ShihabShahriar no, one user's message body will not contain a separate, fully formed message.